Unable to Download .pkpass File to iOS Device
Error: 'Safari cannot download' and 'Cannot install to Passbook at this time' when downloading .pkpass file on iOS
const formBody = `paxList=${encodedPayLoad}`;
const response = await fetch(
    "http://192.168.8.154:8080/accelaero/DownloadMobilePass",
    {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: formBody
    });

if (!response.ok) {
    window.alert(response);
    throw new Error("Failed to save pk pass");
}
else {
    const contentDisposition = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
    let filename = "pass.pkpass"; // Default filename

    if (contentDisposition && contentDisposition.includes('filename=')) {
        const matches = contentDisposition.match(/filename="?([^";]+)"?/);
        if (matches && matches[1]) {
            filename = matches[1]; // Extracted filename
        }
    }

    const rawBlob = await response.blob();
    const blob = new Blob([rawBlob], { type: 'application/vnd.apple.pkpass' })
    const downloadURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = downloadURL;
    a.download = filename;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    const proceedWithDownload = window.confirm(`Do you want to download the file: ${filename}?`);
    if (proceedWithDownload) {
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadURL);
        setTimeout(() => {
            a.remove();

        }, 4e4);
    }


This script was used to download the .pkpass on a mobile device using the browser, but it encountered an error.

Suggestions: Ensure the server endpoint is accessible over https, with the response headers for Content-Type set to application/vnd.apple.pkpass and Content-Disposition set as attachment; filename="pass.pkpass". Then, check if the device correctly prompts you to add the Wallet pass.

This question is similar to: is there is any way possible to download multiple files(.pkpass) on iphone?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
